# How do I checkout an entire SVN repository with all the history, tags and versions

Tags: git, svn, repository, git-svn, svn2git

I have a very large SVN repository (nearly 6000 revisions) which I need to migrate to Git. The repository is hosted on an internal server. I want to migrate all the history, tags and versions to Git and have branches etc in Git format.

So far, I have TortoiseSVN installed on my machine and have been trying to use git svn clone, however, a lot of the folders are too large and I get chunk size errors. At the same time, some files have illegal characters in their file path and so are skipped during migration.

I have also attempted to checkout a working copy into my local machine using TortoiseSVN and then try and migrate it by setting up a local `svnserve` (set up as a Windows service), but, I can never make it work to be able to reach the files using `svn://localhost/...` I followed a guide (https://subversion.open.collab.net/articles/svnserve-service.htm) to set it up as a service and I can reach e.g. `svn://localhost/dev`, but, when I checkout files into this folder via Tortoise, it doesn't see them via `svn://localhost/dev/<sub-folder>` Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but, I'm not sure what.

The structure is as follows:

```
repository (top level)
 - folder 1
   - sub-folder 1
   - sub-folder 2
   - ...
 - folder 2
   - sub-folder 1
   - ...
 - ...
```

Lastly, I have tried to use svn2git, but, I get errors in this case too.

What is the best way to do the migration and/or what am I doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You must convert **repository** in any case, not WC (result of checkout). You can copy repo on local drive and run svnserve (for timeout- and chunk-size problem), or split long history on smaller parts...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

I guess you instead used the nirvdrum `svn2git` one. That one effectively calls `git-svn` and then does some post-processing to overcome some of the drawbacks of `git-svn`, but you get the same errors of course you get with `git-svn`.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories like yours that might exist and including producing several Git repos out of one SVN repo or combining different SVN repos into one Git repo cleanly in one run if you like.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` or the nirvdrum `svn2git` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)